# Multiple devcontainers in vscode-remote

Tags: vscode-remote

I have a project that creates multiple Docker images. I would like to setup a devcontainer in vscode-remote for each image so that I may spin up a container for each image.

I only need to spin up and connect to one container/image at a time.

Is it supported to have multiple devcontainer files? Maybe something like `.devcontainer/devcontainer1.json` and  `.devcontainer/devcontainer2.json` (supposing I only had two images that I wanted to use)?

Each devcontainer would use an image with a different name and also requires different `runArgs`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the other answers too cumbersome as they only work with *F1 -> Dev Containers: Open Folder in Container* and discovered that (with VS Code v1.77) if you place your *devcontainer.json* files in subfolders of .devcontainer it even works with *F1 -> Dev Containers: Reopen in Container* offering you a selection of all your services rightaway without the need to dig through your folder structure.

[image: screenshot VS Code devcontainer selection]

Comment: thank you really. probably the most straightforward.

Comment: Is this VSCode specific, and is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @Arel Can't tell -- never used devcontainers without VSCode. :) I found no specific documentation back then. I think, I discovered it by trying.

Comment: @Arel Update: I just saw that .devcontainer subfolders are actually part of the specs for at least two years: https://containers.dev/implementors/spec/#devcontainerjson -- I just couldn't find a hint in any user-oriented documentation ten months ago. I don't know if the VSCode GUI (resp. the extension) did support this feature from the start.

Answer (score 15):

Just found this here. I checked the documentation because I was interested in this as well. And the documentation states the following

> In some cases, a single container environment isn't sufficient. Fortunately, Remote - Containers supports Docker Compose managed multi-container configurations.
>
> You can either:
>
> 1. Work with a service defined in an existing, unmodified
>    docker-compose.yml.
> 2. Create a new docker-compose.yml (or make a copy of
>    an existing one) that you use to develop a service.
> 3. Extend your existing Docker Compose configuration to develop the service.
> 4. Use separate VS Code windows to work with multiple Docker Compose-defined services at once.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_using-docker-compose

Maybe you want to check this.

Documentation for your use case can be found under the following page:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_connecting-to-multiple-containers-at-once

You do this by using docker-compose.yml and need to have a folder structure like the following:

[image]

Comment: Does this allow you to have `project-root` as the source folder in all containers or is each container restricted to their respective folders?

Comment: I am currently working on it. My current status is, that VS code window gets opened on the subfolder, but I map it to the workspace I can open VSCode for the whole project root manually. I will update my answer with my docker-compose and devcontainer.json as soon as I get something working in basic. 

And FYI: It is a bit problematic to use windows and Unix based images at the same time

Comment: Any updates on project-root?

Comment: I haven't done or researched anything about it since then.

Comment: @Bidski in order to set `project-root` as the workspace root include a `"workspaceFolder"` entry in your `.devcontainer.json` and point it at the location `project-root` on the container - e.g. `"workspaceFolder": "/path/to/project-root"`. Then, even if you "Open Folder in Container..." with `container1-src` VSCode will open with `project-root` as the workspace

Answer (score 2):

You should create another folder `devcontainer2/.devcontainer` and create `devcontainer.json` under that. Also create another dockerfile for 2nd container as `container2.Dockerfile` in your project root.

In your `devcontainer.json` file set the context and dockerFile path correctly. Also if you would like to change workspacefolder you can change it. Refer the below `devcontainer.json`

```json
    {
        "name": "Container2",
    
        // Sets the run context to 2 level up instead of the devcontainer2/.devcontainer folder.
        "context": "../..",
    
        // use the second container file.
        "dockerFile": "../../container2.Dockerfile",
        
        // When dev container is opened, below folder will be in workspace
        "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/project"
    }
```

This link will give you some idea. It talks about how to setup devcontainers in Monorepo. https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/change-default-source-mount

Comment: I've set this up but what command do I execute to build one of these subfolder devcontainers and attach to it?  It seems it's planned but there's no way to actually do it yet... am I missing something?  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7548